# Find maximum value of a equation with optim()

Tags: r

My equation is: function(x){10 * x-x^3+6* x^2-15*x}

The value of x that maximizes this function is **3.528** see:
10* 3.528-3.528^3+6* 3.528^2-15 *3.528

But why when i try to find the value of x that maximizes the function optim give me the wrong value?

```
>optim(c(0),function(x){10*x-x^3+6*x^2-15*x}, control=list(fnscale=-1))$par:
-180925139433306515188282888004820028006042404082666062660624248000000026088
```

[image]

Try with optimize():

```
optimize(function(x){10*x-x^3+6*x^2-15*x},interval = c(-2000,2000),maximum = T)
```

The maximum and the value are also wrong:

```
 $maximum
[1] -2000

$objective
[1] 8024008559
```

[image]

Comment: Leave off `$par` and the output tells you what is wrong.

Comment: I edited the post, the output dont say anything

Comment: You changed it from optim to optimize.  optim certainly does tell you what is wrong.

Comment: When your specify the a large search range the `-x^3` term becomes the dominant term so of course the -(-2000)^3, is the x of the maximum value. Change your search range to some more manageable something like 0 to 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some workarounds:

- With `optimize`

```
optimize(
  function(x) 10 * x - x^3 + 6 * x^2 - 15 * x,
  c(0, .Machine$double.eps**-1),
  maximum = TRUE
)
```

giving

```
$maximum
[1] 3.527528

$objective
[1] 13.12845
```

- With `optim`

```
optim(
  0,
  fn = function(x) 10 * x - x^3 + 6 * x^2 - 15 * x,
  method = "Brent",
  lower = 0,
  upper = .Machine$double.eps**-1,
  control = list(fnscale = -1)
)
```

giving

```
$par
[1] 3.527525

$value
[1] 13.12845

$counts
function gradient
      NA       NA

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

---

If you don't mind using external packages, you can try `fminbnd` from package `pracma`, e.g.,

```
pracma::fminbnd(
  function(x) 10 * x - x^3 + 6 * x^2 - 15 * x,
  0,
  .Machine$double.eps**-1,
  maximum = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
$xmin
[1] 3.527525

$fmin
[1] -13.12845

$niter
[1] 103

$estim.prec
[1] 3.527525e-07
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Seems like there's no global maximum.

Comment: There is a **local** maximum where the OP claims the global maximum is.  Try `curve(ff, from=0, to=5)` (where `ff` is the function)